# Horizontal scrolling in FlatList - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm listing data with flatlist. But while listing the data, it lists it vertically, I want it to be sorted horizontally. So instead of scrolling down, I want to scroll left and right. I think it's called pagingEnabled. How can I do that?

```
<FlatList
                    style={{
                        flex: 1

                    }}
                    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    data={this.state.allReasons}
                    keyExtractor={(item,index)=>index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item ,index}) => {
                        return (

                          <ScrollView onScroll={(event)=>{
                    this.setState({
                        activePage:Math.round(parseFloat(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x/Dimensions.get('window').width))
                    })
               
            }}
            style={{width:'100%'}} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} pagingEnabled={true} horizontal={true}>

                                       <View style={{width:'100%'}}>
             

   <Image style={{   resizeMode: 'contain',width:Dimensions.get('window').width,height:250}} source={{uri:"http://ledslider.stechomeyazilim.com/" + item.Slider_Image}}/>
 .....

 </View>
```

Comment: Do you want to have horizontal scrolling items in the flatlist ?

Comment: Yes I want exactly what you say @GuruparanGiritharan

Comment: Is your content width longer? you set the width of 100% , add some without setting the width n see

Comment: When I make horizontal enabled, only the first item appears, except for the first item. @GuruparanGiritharan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add horizontal prop in Flatlist like

```
horizontal={true}
```

Try removing scrollview from item may cause the issue

Comment: Try removing scrollview from item may cause the issue